# SQL: Unioning 2 tables and then joining on another. Is there a better way of doing this?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union-all

I have to maintain an application who's database is a little haywire and I had the following challenge to join 3 tables:

table1
timestamp,zid,aaa

table2
timestamp,zid,bbb

table3
id,some,other,data

So table 1 and 2 need to be joined and sorted on their timestamp columns. I also need to preserve table1's aaa and table2's bbb column and be able to distinguish whether its an aaa or a bbb. Then I need to join it to another table via their zid column.

Here is my working sql for this:

```
SELECT *

FROM 
    table3
    LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT  table1.timestamp AS timestamp, 
        table1.zid, 
        table1.aaa AS responses,
        'aaas'
    FROM table1

    UNION ALL
    SELECT  table2.timestamp AS timestamp, 
        table2.zid,
        table2.aaa AS responses,
        'bbbs'
    FROM table2

    ) aaasAndbbbs ON table3.id = aaasAndbbbs.zid

ORDER BY timestamp ASC;
```

The above sql does exactly what I want, but I want to know if there is a better way. Here I use the "aaas" column to distinguish whether it is an aaa or a bbb- which seems a little hacky. Is there a preferable way to do what I want?

Comment: You're not really joining table1 and table2, you're just combining the data sets. An additional column that defines where the source field came from seems to be the right way to do this. How else would you be able to know if the data came from the 'aaa' column or the 'bbb' column, without some kind of flag? What's the business use of these tables? 'aaa' and 'bbb' are very generic...

Comment: the aaas column is the flag I'm using. I also currently cannot modify the database

Comment: @user1028270 : Can you tell a bit more about nature of the data in table1 and table2 ? I'd try to avoid `UNION` for performance sake if it's possible (for instance, if table1 contains current data, and table2 has historical, the query can be easily rewritten without union).

Comment: Its kind of a mess, but these tables have text input by users in a cms kind of system. Table3 contains sort of like the main threads information, table1 is a regular response and table2 is a "note"- which is just a special response. The responses and notes need to appear chronologically via the timestamp, need to be identified as a response or a note, and be joined to the main "thread" with various other information. I asked this question because I know unions should be avoided. In my case I was thinking it was the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative would be to do each one separately and you will see the LEFT JOIN to table 3 is duplicated. I suspect however that if you look at the Execution plan for both your version and my version that they will be the same. The SQL Server Optimiser should be clever enough to figure out that both are doing the same thing and hence execute both in the same way. I find this slightly more readable than yours but that's my preference!

```
SELECT  table1.timestamp AS timestamp, 
    table1.zid, 
    table1.aaa AS responses,
    'aaas'
FROM table3 
LEFT JOIN table1 on table3.id = table1.zid

UNION

SELECT  table2.timestamp AS timestamp, 
    table2.zid,
    table2.aaa AS responses,
    'bbbs'
FROM table3
LEFT JOIN table1 on table3.id = table2.zid
ORDER BY timestamp ASC;
```

Comment: OP is selecting from `table3` and then left joining table1,table2, not vice versa. Your `LEFT JOIN`s have to be `RIGHT JOIN`s to return the same results as in the question.

Comment: hmm tried to run this with right joins as per the comment and the query is taking a long time to execute...

Comment: ;) rather than adding right joins, I swapped the tables in the from clause and the join clause round which matches your query. If you now amend them to right joins you will encounter my error again! Try the answer as it is.

Comment: How do I select the other columns from table3 with this query?

Comment: Also using that query it seems I cannot use a where clause to search on table3's id? If I put the following line at the bottom of that query it does not do anything: WHERE table3.id = '123456'

Comment: That is because its only applying the where clause to the second query. If you want to apply a where clause to both, I would go with your current answer otherwise you will end up duplicating code and it will look messy with my alternate answer.

Comment: Actually I might use your as mine cannot be made a view due to the sub query.